# Why is my boxplot not showing up in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I am new to Python and am working on displaying a boxplot for a dataset with 2 numeric columns and 1 character column with values (A,B,C,D).  I want to show a boxplot of the values for either of the 2 numeric columns by the character column.  I have followed some tutorials online but the plots are not showing up.

I have tried adding .show() or .plot() on the end of some of my code, but receive warnings that those attributes don't exist.  I have tried using matplotlib and it seems to work better when I use that module, but I want to learn how to do this when using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
datafile="C:\\Users\\…\\TestFile.xlsx"
data=pd.read_excel(datafile)
data.boxplot('Col1', by='Col2')
```

I want a boxplot to show up automatically when I run this code or be able to run one more line to have it pop up, but everything I've tried has failed.  What step(s) am I missing?

Comment: `plt.show()` shows the plot (`plt` is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `plt.show()`. Look at the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
datafile="C:\\Users\\…\\TestFile.xlsx"
data=pd.read_excel(datafile)
data.boxplot('Col1', by='Col2')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Typo in the import statement, correction  -->  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: this solution is not working

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn library helps you plot all sorts of plots between two columns of a dataframe pretty easily. Place any categorical column on the x-axis and a numerical column on the y-axis. There is also a fancy version of boxplot in Seaborn known as `boxenplot`.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(x = data['Col1'], y = data['Col2'])


import seaborn as sns
sns.boxenplot(x = data['Col1'], y = data['Col2'])
```

Comment: While this code may/may no solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations.